# Generic tree of generic node C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to create a generic tree class of generic node objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tree<Node<int>> tree = new Tree<Node<int>>();
    }
}

public class Tree<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Node<TNode> : IComparable<TNode>
    where TNode : IComparable<TNode>
{
    TNode Value;
    public int CompareTo(TNode other)
    {
        return Value.CompareTo(other);
    }
}
```

But in the main method I'm receiving compilation error:

```
The type 'BinaryTree.Node<int>' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Tree<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'BinaryTree.Node<int>' to 'System.IComparable<BinaryTree.Node<int>>'.
```

Can someone help me understand what is the problem?

Comment: You have stated that `Node<T>` can be compared to `T`. You need: `class Node<TNode> : IComparable<Node<TNode>>` (notice I added Node to the interface there)

Comment: That would mean I could compare node with a node, but what I want to do is compare node value with other value using IComparable interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you got confused by your naming standard, just as I were.

This declaration has a problem:

```
public class Node<TNode> : IComparable<TNode>
    where TNode : IComparable<TNode>
```

Let's rewrite it by renaming the generic parameter:

```
public class Node<T> : IComparable<T>
    where TNode : IComparable<T>
```

Here you can see that you declared it as being able to be compared against the values it stores, not against other nodes.

Since the tree type requires *its* `T` to be able to compare against values of the same type, you need the nodes to be able to compare against other nodes, like this:

```
                                   changed
                                   v-----v
public class Node<T> : IComparable<Node<T>>
    where TNode : IComparable<TNode>
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is in your `Node<>` class - you've said that a `Node` is comparable to the type of value inside it. Instead, you should say it's comparable to another *node* with the same value:

```cs
public class Node<TNode> : IComparable<Node<TNode>>
    where TNode : IComparable<TNode>
{
    TNode Value;
    public int CompareTo(Node<TNode> other)
    {
        return Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
    }
}
```

At that point, it's find to create a `Tree<Node<int>>`.

But it might be better to actually create a `Tree<int>`, and make `Tree<T>` use `Node<T>` internally instead. That's likely to be easier to use. After all, every tree will have nodes. It's hard to say for sure with relatively little code, but I suspect that's actually what you want to do.